# sql self join and many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, database

i have a tabled called category and a record can have a parent or a child and this category. the category tables is a many-to-many relationship with posts through post_category.

```
category[id, name category_id]

posts[id,title, body....]

post_cats[id,post_id,category_id]
```

sample data

```
category
id    name     category_id
1     xxxx      0
2     yyyy      0
3     ZZZZ      1
4     WWWW      1
5     AAAA      2
6     BBBB      2



posts
id    title              body
1     aaaaaaaaaa
2     bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
3     ccccccccccccccc
4     ddddddddddd

post_cats
id  post_id       category_id
1    1                 3
2    1                 4
3    2                 5
4    2                 6
5    2                 3
```

category record one has a post of 3 and record two has a post of 2
i want to count all posts that belongs to the category name 'xxxx' or simply want to count all posts belongs to each parent category with their child category counted.

Comment: I can't understand the question as it's currently phrased. Could you add some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Have you an approach, which you have tried already?

Comment: not quite understood the relations of classes: 1. post belongs to many categories, and category belongs to many categories too? 2. post has many categories too?

Answer (score 0):

```
select post_id
from   post_category
group by post_id 
having count(*) = (select count(*) from category)
```

Comment: Hello Dmitry,i want to count all parent category. let give u some hint a parent category will have some child category and each child category is many to many with posts through post_category. i want to count all record of a child record and sum them to their parent so the parent will have the same of all child category of posts.

Comment: that isn't for rails, but is just a query. For it should be a rails/arel friendly record.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to count the posts for each top level category?

Comment: ya that is correct i want to count all posts related to their top parent category

Answer (score 0):

just try this scheme using the [arel](/questions/tagged/arel) gem:

```
class ParentCategory < ...
   has_many :categories

   scope :posts, -> do 
      Post.joins(:categories)
          .where(Post.arel_table[:id].eq(Category.arel_table[:post_id])
            .and(Category.arel_table[:parent_category_id].eq(arel_table[:id])))
   end
end
```